# Liferay Service Builder: Reverse engineer existing DDL into service.xml

Tags: liferay, liferay-service-builder

Anyone developed some tools or have some ideas on how reverse engineer an existing database model (DDL) into Service Builder definition (service.xml) ?

Thank you for any contribution on this

Ivano C.

Comment: Sorry, I never heared anything about, but I'm sure it can be a good idea for future developments...

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of information to find about *connecting service builder code to existing databases* (use search terms similar to this). AFAIK no tools, but `service.xml` can cater for it. Some of the information is hacky, some old-ish, but service builder didn't change that much over times, so you still can find good information.

First of all, you should check [service-builder's DTD](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/definitions/liferay-service-builder_6_2_0.dtd.html), which - apart from the usual technical DTD stuff - has 95% comments & documentation. That alone might answer your questions.

Another thing to keep in mind is: [When you already have an existing business layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047712) you might not have a big advantage by throwing it away and subordinate to service builder's assumptions of how the world looks like.

Comment: Dear Olaf, thank you for your clear and precise advices on using Service Builder when we already have an existing business layer.  In fact my use case is a bit different:
I'm creating my Data model starting from XSD definition.
Then from this XSD definition I'll create the the DDL
(Database Definition Language) necessary to create a database backend.
Finally, from DDL I'll create my service.xml and use Service Builder to manage my business and persistence layer.
This scenario bring me to ask for a tool or advise me on how create service.xml from standard DDL.

Comment: ...in that case xslt might be a choice. Not really a ready-to-use-tool, rather a tool to create tools. I don't expect any ready-to-use tool to be found in that case

Comment: I understood, using XSLT I have to transfrom the DDL document into service.xml.
Thank you to teach me this !
Ivano C.